# Adding space in front of each line in ansible block

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to add a block in a file with space in front of it. Ansible script i used is given below.

```
- name: Disable Apache Directory listing, Symbolic Links, Server side includes and CGI execution 
  blockinfile:
    dest: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    insertbefore: '</VirtualHost>'
    block: |
      Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  -Includes -ExecCGI
      LimitRequestBody  10485760
```

But output i am getting is given below :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  -Includes -ExecCGI
LimitRequestBody  10485760
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
</VirtualHost>
```

What i am expecting is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  -Includes -ExecCGI
    LimitRequestBody  10485760
    # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
</VirtualHost>
```

We can't use space in front of **blockinfile** code like we use in **line**

```
line: '        Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  -Includes -ExecCGI'
```

How can we do it any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use yaml Block Indentation Indicator:

```
- name: Disable Apache Directory listing, Symbolic Links, Server side includes and CGI execution 
  blockinfile:
    dest: testfile.conf
    insertbefore: '</VirtualHost>'
    block: |4
            Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  -Includes -ExecCGI
            LimitRequestBody  10485760
```

This will give:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks  -Includes -ExecCGI
    LimitRequestBody  10485760 
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the indentation in the block is important for this to work correctly.

https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793979